# How to set DateTimePicker to certain time and keep the customized date?

Tags: c#

In windows forms C#, I want to set `DateTimePicker` to certain `time` and keep the customized `date` (any `date` I select from `dateTimePicker`) when button is clicked.

for example:

Say we have this date and time: `2015-08-15 08:30:00` I want when I click button the `date` stays same and the `time` changes to `11:30:00`.

I mean if I select any `date` from `dateTimePicker` and then click button, the `date` remains same and `time` change to `11:30:00` .

Please help me to achieve this.

I might need to modify the following code to achieve what I want:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(11.5); // shows you  current date and 11:30:00 time


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now; // shows you  current date and time

    }
```

Comment: Add the hours to the `dateTimePicker1.Value` instead of `DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set it to a custom format then set the time to what you want

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt";

    DateTimePicker1 .Value = new DateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, DateTimePicker1.Value.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, 0);
}
```

This will retain you whatever Date you have currently set in your datetime picker, and will just update the time since the custome formate forces time into it.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt";

    DateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value.Month, DateTimePicker1.Value.Day, 15, 23, 0);
}
```

Will retain the date and force the time to 3:23 PM.

Just to note there is also

`DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;` That will set the exact date and time of your current computer.

`DateTime.Now.Year` Gets current year

`DateTime.Now.Month` Gets current month

`DateTime.Now.Day` Gets current day

You can use all these to manipulate your datetime picker how you please.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something similar to this a while ago.  I ended up having two datetimepickers next to each other, one for the date and the other for the time.  Then on the value changed event of each of them I set the value of both date time pickers appropriately.  For instance if I had
`dtpDate` and `dtpTime`, then

```
    private void dtpTime_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
    {
        dtpDate.Value = dtpDate.Value.Date + dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay
    }
    private void dtpDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
    {
        dtpTime.Value = dtpDate.Value.Date + dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay
    }
```